# buf generate - .proto not exists

Tags: go, grpc, buf

When I run `buf generate`, get error:

> proto/auth_service.proto:5:8:user.proto: does not exist

`buf.gen.yaml`:

```
version: v1
plugins:
  - name: go
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
  - name: go-grpc
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
  - name: grpc-gateway
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
      - generate_unbound_methods=true
  - name: openapiv2
    out: swagger-ui/gen/openapiv2/
```

The proto files are in `proto/`, there are only 2 file, 1 file import the other via:

> import "user.proto";

So, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

After adding `buf.work.yaml`:

```
version: v1
directories:
  - proto
```

now it works.

---

### To find 3rd party dependencies specified via `deps`

- Need to add `buf.yaml` inside the module, aka. the dir contain .proto files. It maybe a sub dir where `buf.gen.yaml` and `buf.work.yaml` resides.
- Seems `buf.md` should be put in the same dir with `buf.yaml`, though it doesn't effect the build. It effects the doc on buf.build site.
- When run `buf mod update` should be within the dir where `buf.yaml` exists, or should specify the dir, e.g `buf mod update proto/`.
- If u are using `goland`, install the `buf` plugin, to make the .proto files able to find the `deps` in IDE, though it doesn't effects but the build itself.
- 

---

### Refer

- https://docs.buf.build/configuration/v1beta1-migration-guide#buildroots
- https://github.com/bufbuild/buf/issues/201#issuecomment-1466150107
- https://github.com/bufbuild/buf/issues/1911
- https://docs.buf.build/tutorials/getting-started-with-bsr
- https://github.com/bufbuild/buf-tour/tree/main/finish/getting-started-with-bsr